# Form - button group with same "name" value

Tags: php, html, forms

I tried to make form with some inputs that insert data in my database, the problem is - one of inputs (button group with name "priority" can't be find by PHP interpreter. Where I should put that name? I think it was bad... Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong><label for="towho">Do kogo:</label></strong>
    <select class="form-control" name="towho">
        <option> - - - </option>
        <!-- Skrypt pobierania danych (username) do Selecta -->
        <?php
            get_users();
        ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <hr></hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Temat:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="topic">
    </div>
    <hr></hr>
        <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px">
            <strong><label for="comment">Opis zadania:</label></strong>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
        <center>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong><p>Priorytet:</p></strong>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="WYSOKI" name="priority">
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="ŚREDNI" name="priority">
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="NISKI" name="priority">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </center>
        <hr></hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button name="submit" type="worksubmit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Zaakceptuj</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'db.php';

$sf = "INSERT INTO zadania (id, user, tablename, dodano, dokogo, tytul, opis, priorytet, zaakceptowano, status) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['valid_user']."', 'zadania', '".date('d.m.Y')."', '".$_POST['towho']."', '".$_POST['topic']."', '".$_POST['comment']."', '".$_POST['priority']."', '2018-01-01 1:00:00', 'start')";

mysqli_query($conn,$sf);
echo "Succes";
```

And everything works fine, only that "priority" doesn't work. It show **UNDEFINED INDEX "priority"**  onto my INPUT query. Also... My buttons can't be wide on whole form, their width is defined by chars, but my intentions were different.

Comment: its not working on input type button. try using radio button or checkbox .. input type button does not have checked and selected attributes.

Comment: Thank you, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use JQUERY to change the value of a hidden input field named priority and when either button is pressed change the value.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#priority1").click(function(){
    $("#priority").attr("value", "WYSOKI");
  });
  $("#priority2").click(function(){
    $("#priority").attr("value", "ŚREDNI");
  });
  $("#priority3").click(function(){
    $("#priority").attr("value", "NISKI");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
    <strong><label for="towho">Do kogo:</label></strong>
    <select class="form-control" name="towho">
        <option> - - - </option>
        <!-- Skrypt pobierania danych (username) do Selecta -->
        <?php
            get_users();
        ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <hr></hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Temat:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="topic">
    </div>
    <hr></hr>
        <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px">
            <strong><label for="comment">Opis zadania:</label></strong>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
        <center>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong><p>Priorytet:</p></strong>
            <input type="text" value="" id="priority" name="priority" hidden>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="WYSOKI" id="priority1">
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="ŚREDNI" id="priority2">
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="NISKI" id="priority3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </center>
        <hr></hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button name="submit" type="worksubmit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Zaakceptuj</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```